# Replacing text in order to change pitch/key

Tags: ios, swift, string, textview

I'm having a huge difficult about my code. I'm developing an app that shows lyrics and chords of songs. I separated chords and lyrics using two overlying textviews.

The problem that I got in this project is the pitch alteration function. I try to explain me as better as I can:

The chords are 12 in all: Do-Do#-Re-Re#-Mi-Fa-Fa#-Sol-Sol#-La-La#-Si

I use two buttons + and - to change the pitch

In order to contain spaces from a chord to another I used `replacingOccurrences(of:with:options:)` instance method in this way:

```
//MARK: - Change pitch 
    @IBAction func risePitch(_ sender: UIButton) {

                //positive side was pressed
                let dosre = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Do#", with: "Re", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = dosre

                let dodos = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Do", with: "Do#", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = dodos

                let resmi = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Re#", with: "Mi", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = resmi

                let remi = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Re", with: "Re#", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = remi

                let fassol = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Fa#", with: "Sol", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = fassol

                let mifa = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Mi", with: "Fa", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = mifa

                let fafas = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Fa", with: "Fa#", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = fafas

                let solsla = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Sol#", with: "La", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = solsla

                let solsols = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Sol", with: "Sol#", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = solsols

                let lassi = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "La#", with: "Si", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = lassi

                let lalas = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "La", with: "La#", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = lalas

                let sido = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Si", with: "Do", options: .widthInsensitive)
                chords.text = sido

    }


    @IBAction func decreasePitch(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //negative side was pressed
        let dosre = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Do#", with: "Do", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = dosre

        let dore = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Do", with: "Si", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = dore

        let resmi = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Re#", with: "Re", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = resmi

        let remi = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Re", with: "Do#", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = remi

        let mifa = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Mi", with: "Re#", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = mifa

        let fassol = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Fa#", with: "Fa", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = fassol

        let fafas = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Fa", with: "Mi", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = fafas

        let solsla = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Sol#", with: "Sol", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = solsla

        let solsols = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Sol", with: "Fa#", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = solsols

        let lassi = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "La#", with: "La", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = lassi

        let lalas = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "La", with: "Sol#", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = lalas

        let sido = chords.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "Si", with: "La#", options: .widthInsensitive)
        chords.text = sido


    }
```

If you run this code you will see that the pitch conversion do not work properly.

Hope I has been enough clear....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be much easier if you split the notes out into an array of strings (and have a temporary array to make edits to), and then have the raise and lower pitch functions +1 or -1 to each note each time. You can then collapse the chord array into a string to display it. This code here works:

```
var masterChords = ["Do",  "Do#",  "Re",  "Re#",  "Mi",  "Fa",  "Fa#",  "Sol",  "Sol#",  "La",  "La#",  "Si"]
var chords = ["Do", "Sol", "Mi"]

func raisePitch() {
    for i in 0...chords.count - 1 {
        for j in 0...masterChords.count - 1 {
            if chords[i] == masterChords[j] {
                if j < masterChords.count - 1 {
                    chords[i] = masterChords[j + 1]
                    break
                } else {
                    chords[i] = masterChords[0]
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func lowerPitch() {
    for i in 0...chords.count - 1 {
        for j in 0...masterChords.count - 1 {
            if chords[i] == masterChords[j] {
                if j > 0 {
                    chords[i] = masterChords[j - 1]
                    break
                } else {
                    chords[i] = masterChords[masterChords.count - 1]
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//Use the code below to test
print(chords)

raisePitch()

print(chords)

lowerPitch()

print(chords)

lowerPitch()

print(chords)
```

Comment: Thank you so much to answer me so fast Simba. Yes this works very well, however in a real case we have different chords to alterate. For example: let chords = ["Do", "Sol","Mi"] in that case rising +1 this should become ["Do#","Sol#","Fa"]

Comment: No problem - I've updated the code so that it has a masterChords array (that just holds all the possible notes) and a chords array (which holds the notes you want to raise or lower). The code now compares the two arrays, and where the note in the chord array matches the respective note in the masterChords array, it raises/lowers it by one note. Hope this helps!